# sprint to html file placeholder

Tags: php

i would like to pass a value to external html file using sprintf. What i have tried so far:

external html file:

```
<html><body><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%%;padding:25px 20px 25px 20px;background:#f2f2f2;"><tr><td>%s</td></tr></table></body></html>
```

php file:

```
 $html = "../../email-templates/registration-template.html";
 $html = sprintf($html,"myvalue");
 $mime->setHTMLBody($html, true);
```

i have escaped the % used for the css property but i keep getting %s and not "myvalue"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aparently it was not a big deal; i found a solution ...i get the html content of the external file using file_get_contents() method and in setHTMLBody() i passed the content as text and not as file

```
$html = sprintf(file_get_contents("../../email-templates/registration-template.html"), "myvalue");

$mime->setHTMLBody($html);
```